# RabbitMQ: how to use amqps?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a c# application (NET Framework 4.5) and RabbitMQ.Client (3.6.9).
When I use this:

```
 ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory
                {
                    Uri = "amqp://xxx.xxx.xxx.27",
                    UserName = "guest",
                    Password = "guest"
                };
```

it connects to the broker fine.
If I use Uri = "amqps://xxx.xxx.xxx.27"
then I receive an error

```
Error: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
```

How I can use amqps ?
Note. AWS RabbitMQ required amqps.

Comment: Do you need to specify a port number? With the "secure" version, you probably need to specify more settings, like certificates.

Comment: I use port by default, but the problem is I should use NET 4.5+RabbitMQClient 3.6.9.. If I use NET 4.8+RabbitMQ 6.* the amqps works fine. I need 4.5. because my target is SQLCLR.